Postgres Docker container does not start with a custom shell script
I have a docker-compose file with a Postgres image. The service definition is as follows:
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - "{{ docker_dir }}/postgressql/data:/var/lib/postgressql/data"
      - "{{ docker_compose_dir }}/postgres/initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB : '{{ container_variables.postgres.db }}'
      POSTGRES_USER : '{{ container_variables.postgres.db_user }}'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD :  '{{ container_variables.postgres.db_password }}'
    networks:
      - backend
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: ["sh","-c","chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/custom_entrypoint.sh && /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/custom_entrypoint.sh"]

I want to execute a shell script after starting the container.
#!/bin/bash
set -e

until pg_isready -h postgres -p 5432 -U postgres
do
  echo "Waiting for postgres"
  sleep 10;
done

echo "do something ...."

At container startup, I receive the following output in the log:
Waiting for postgres
postgres:5432 - no response

Even if I replace the execution of the shell script with a simple echo, I still can't get the container to run. When I start the container without the command, it works perfectly

Do you want the script to run on initial startup, or every time your system starts up?  Is it specifically tied to the database startup, something else starting up (is it a migration script, for example, connected to your application code), or something else?  Your most notable problem here is that command: runs instead of the normal container command, so you're trying to run your script instead of launching a database (not in addition to).

The script should run every time the container starts. Is there a way to run the Command command in addition to the container's normal Command command?

It's typically easier to run things like this in a separate container, or in another existing container's entrypoint wrapper script.  What does the script actually do?

I want to run some sql commands
